# C++, priority queue, items are not sorted

Tags: c++, sorting, priority-queue

I have a problem with the priority queue:

```
std::priority_queue <NodePrio, std::vector<NodePrio>, sortNodesByPrio> PQ;
```

where

```
struct NodePrio
{
Node *node;
double priority;

NodePrio() : node(NULL), priority(0) {}
NodePrio(Node *node_, double priority_) : node(node_), priority(priority_) {}
};
```

and

```
class sortNodesByPrio
{
public:
    bool operator () (const NodePrio &n1, const NodePrio  &n2)   const;
}


bool sortNodesByPrio::operator () (const NodePrio &n1, const NodePrio &n2) const
{
return n1.priority < n2.priority;
}
```

After repeatedly pushing new elements

```
PQ.push(NodePrio(node, distance));
```

and from any point in time they are not sorted (see bellow)... I tried to debug the code, the comparator code has been repeatedly performed...

```
Step1: 
push (node, 55.33);

PQ:
[0] 55.33

Step2:
push (node, 105.91);

PQ:
[0] 105.91
[1] 55.33

Step 3:
push (node, 45.18);

PQ:
[0] 105.91
[1] 55.33
[2] 45.18

Step 4:
push (node, 70.44);

PQ:
[0] 105.91
[1] 70.44
[2] 45.18
[3] 55.33   //Bad sort
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they are not sorted?"  Can you post some sample data that you are inputting and the result when you pop all the data out of the priority queue?

Comment: Can you give an example or two of your input and what the resulting contents of the queue is? Also, what did you try in the way of debugging so far?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the "sample results" you show, it looks like you don't understand what a priority queue is.

A priority queue guarantees that when you remove elements from it (using `top()` and `pop()`), the elements will be removed in priority order.  The elements are not stored in priority order, they are stored in a heap.

You can consult your favorite algorithms book or website for more information on how a priority queue stores its elements.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now it's clear. I thought that all elements are sorted like in the map, but the key duplication is allowed.

Comment: You'll want `std::multimap` for that.

Comment: @suszterpatt. I do not think at all. I knew, how PQ works, but I was completely wrong about internal storage of items.

Comment: @Ian:  The elements are not sorted as in a `std::map`.  In common `std::map` implementations, elements are sorted in a binary search tree so that elements can be retrieved in sorted order by performing an in-order traversal of the tree.  This is not the case for a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
return n1.priority() < n2.priority();
```

to

```
return n1.priority < n2.priority;
```

Comment: dumb question: what does adding () to a variable do?

Comment: @Markus:  That would make it a function call; it would be valid if `priority` was of some type that could be called as a function taking no arguments, but since it's a `double`, adding `()` to it makes the code ill-formed.  My guess is that the OP didn't copy and paste his exact code; there is another syntax error as well.

Comment: @Rohit: I am sorry, it was my mistake posting the code.... The original source code is correct.